# Creating columns for each observed value of a variable

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose a respondent (id) is asked to make a choice in five tasks (t=1,2,3,4,5) (a panel dataset with five observations per respondent). Once, a choice is made then an outcome is shown to the respondent. Suppose the data look like below.

```
+----+---+---------+
| id | t | outcome |
+----+---+---------+
|  1 | 1 |      10 |
|  1 | 2 |      20 |
|  1 | 3 |      30 |
|  1 | 4 |      40 |
|  1 | 5 |      40 |
|  2 | 1 |      20 |
|  2 | 2 |      30 |
|  2 | 3 |      40 |
|  2 | 4 |      40 |
|  2 | 5 |      20 |
|  . | . |       . |
|  . | . |       . |
|  . | . |       . |
+----+---+---------+
```

Now, I am interested to keep the history of the **outcome** variable for each *t-1* task. I am aiming for the below output.

```
+----+---+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| id | t | outcome | outcome_t1 | outcome_t2 | outcome_t3 | outcome_t4 | outcome_t5 |
+----+---+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|  1 | 1 |      10 | NA         | NA         | NA         | NA         | NA         |
|  1 | 2 |      20 | 10         | NA         | NA         | NA         | NA         |
|  1 | 3 |      30 | 10         | 20         | NA         | NA         | NA         |
|  1 | 4 |      40 | 10         | 20         | 30         | NA         | NA         |
|  1 | 5 |      40 | 10         | 20         | 30         | 40         | NA         |
|  2 | 1 |      20 | NA         | NA         | NA         | NA         | NA         |
|  2 | 2 |      30 | 20         | NA         | NA         | NA         | NA         |
|  2 | 3 |      40 | 20         | 30         | NA         | NA         | NA         |
|  2 | 4 |      40 | 20         | 30         | 40         | NA         | NA         |
|  2 | 5 |      20 | 20         | 30         | 40         | 40         | NA         |
|  . | . |       . | .          | .          | .          | .          | .          |
|  . | . |       . | .          | .          | .          | .          | .          |
|  . | . |       . | .          | .          | .          | .          | .          |
+----+---+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

I went through most of the questions on this forum, but most of them address the lagged columns which are not applicable to this case.

Perhaps there could be an easy and efficient way using `mutate` with `dplyr` but I am unable to make it work so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base R approach, we can `split` the `outcome` column based on `id` and create a dataframe incrementally adding one value at a time in `outcome` variable and filling rest of them with `NA` and finally `rbind` these list of dataframes into one dataframe.

```
n <- 5
df[paste0("outcome_t", seq_len(n))] <- do.call(rbind, 
    lapply(split(df$outcome, df$id), function(x) 
  t(sapply(seq_along(x), function(y) c(x[seq_len(y - 1)], rep(NA, n - (y - 1)))))))

df
#   id t outcome outcome_t1 outcome_t2 outcome_t3 outcome_t4 outcome_t5
#1   1 1      10         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
#2   1 2      20         10         NA         NA         NA         NA
#3   1 3      30         10         20         NA         NA         NA
#4   1 4      40         10         20         30         NA         NA
#5   1 5      40         10         20         30         40         NA
#6   2 1      20         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
#7   2 2      30         20         NA         NA         NA         NA
#8   2 3      40         20         30         NA         NA         NA
#9   2 4      40         20         30         40         NA         NA
#10  2 5      20         20         30         40         40         NA
```

---

A `tidyverse` option using `separate`

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(new = map_chr(seq_along(outcome), 
         ~paste0(outcome[seq_len(. - 1)], collapse = ","))) %>%
   separate(new, into = paste0("outcome_t", seq_len(n)), 
                 sep = ",", fill = "right") %>%
   mutate(outcome_t1 = replace(outcome_t1, outcome_t1 == "", NA))
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(id = rep(c(1, 2), each = 5), t = 1:5, 
     outcome = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 40, 20, 30, 40, 40, 20))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table` methods for this.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'id', loop through the 'outcome', `rep`licate the elements with the specifying the sequence from `1:.N` and `.N:1` with NA as padding, then join with the original dataset on the 'id' and 't' columns

```
library(data.table)
df2 <- setDT(df1)[, Map(function(x, y, z) rep(c(NA, x), 
             c(y, z)), outcome, 1:.N, .N:1), id][, t := rowid(id)]
out <- df2[df1, on  = .(id, t)]
setcolorder(out, c(1, 7, 8, 2:6))
setnames(out, 4:ncol(out), paste0("outcome_t", 1:5))
out
#    id t outcome outcome_t1 outcome_t2 outcome_t3 outcome_t4 outcome_t5
# 1:  1 1      10         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
# 2:  1 2      20         10         NA         NA         NA         NA
# 3:  1 3      30         10         20         NA         NA         NA
# 4:  1 4      40         10         20         30         NA         NA
# 5:  1 5      40         10         20         30         40         NA
# 6:  2 1      20         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
# 7:  2 2      30         20         NA         NA         NA         NA
# 8:  2 3      40         20         30         NA         NA         NA
# 9:  2 4      40         20         30         40         NA         NA
#10:  2 5      20         20         30         40         40         NA
```

---

Or an option with `dcast`

```
dcast(setDT(df1), id + t ~ paste0("outcome_t", t), 
       value.var = 'outcome')[, na.locf(.SD, na.rm = FALSE), id]
```

---

Or we can do this more compactly

```
library(zoo)
nm1 <- paste0("outcome_t", 1:5)
df1[nm1] <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df1$outcome, df1$id), 
                function(x) head(rbind(NA, na.locf((NA^!diag(x)) * x)), -1)))
```

---

Or using `colCumsums`

```
library(matrixStats)
df1[nm1] <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df1$outcome, df1$id), 
          function(x) colCumsums(rbind(0, diag(x)))[-length(x), ]))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
t = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), outcome = c(10L, 
20L, 30L, 40L, 40L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 40L, 20L)),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another data.table approach using `transpose`:

```
DT[, paste0("outcome_t", 1:5) := 
        transpose(lapply(t, function(x) replace(outcome, t>=x, NA))), 
    by=.(id)]
```

output:

```
    id t outcome outcome_t1 outcome_t2 outcome_t3 outcome_t4 outcome_t5
 1:  1 1      10         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
 2:  1 2      20         10         NA         NA         NA         NA
 3:  1 3      30         10         20         NA         NA         NA
 4:  1 4      40         10         20         30         NA         NA
 5:  1 5      40         10         20         30         40         NA
 6:  2 1      20         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
 7:  2 2      30         20         NA         NA         NA         NA
 8:  2 3      40         20         30         NA         NA         NA
 9:  2 4      40         20         30         40         NA         NA
10:  2 5      20         20         30         40         40         NA
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("| id | t | outcome |
|  1 | 1 |      10 |
|  1 | 2 |      20 |
|  1 | 3 |      30 |
|  1 | 4 |      40 |
|  1 | 5 |      40 |
|  2 | 1 |      20 |
|  2 | 2 |      30 |
|  2 | 3 |      40 |
|  2 | 4 |      40 |
|  2 | 5 |      20 |")[, c(-1,-5)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(rn = 1:n(),
         t = paste0("outcome_t", t)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  spread(t, outcome) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-rn, -id), lag) %>%
  fill(-rn, -id)

# A tibble: 10 x 7
# Groups:   id [2]
      id    rn outcome_t1 outcome_t2 outcome_t3 outcome_t4 outcome_t5
   <int> <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>
 1     1     1         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
 2     1     2         10         NA         NA         NA         NA
 3     1     3         10         20         NA         NA         NA
 4     1     4         10         20         30         NA         NA
 5     1     5         10         20         30         40         NA
 6     2     6         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
 7     2     7         20         NA         NA         NA         NA
 8     2     8         20         30         NA         NA         NA
 9     2     9         20         30         40         NA         NA
10     2    10         20         30         40         40         NA
```